# How to select a value and then update a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one that stores the the id of the an old img

```
 id | old_img_name | old_img_id
```

and another table that stores the info of the current img

```
id |img_name | img_w | img_h | etc....
```

and im trying to create a query to update(switch) the info from the old table into the new one, the only field that I want to update is the img_name.

I have create two queries to do that :

```
SELECT id, old_img_id, old_img_name FROM `img_archives` WHERE id = 3

UPDATE imgs SET img_name = old_img_name  WHERE id = old_img_id
```

I want to convine these two queries into one, but I'm having a lot or problem doing it.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE imgs SET img_name = img_archives_old_img_name FROM imgs INNER JOIN img_archives ON imgs_id = img_archives.old_img_id;
```

not is not working

Comment: Why is it not working?  What part is not working?

Comment: Also if you want to update the image name from one table to another why is the img_name hardcoded to test?

Comment: Because that were I'm lost, i don't know how to get the name from the other table in one query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE imgs i INNER JOIN img_archives ia ON i.imgs_id = ia.old_img_id SET i.img_name = ia.old_img_name;
```

more info is here:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

Answer (score 1):

```
-- this should do it
UPDATE imgs 
SET img_name = img_archives.old_img_name   
FROM imgs 
INNER JOIN img_archives ON imgs_id = img_archives.old_img_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In mysql the update with join should use this sintax 
If you want update the id  = 3

```
UPDATE imgs 
INNER JOIN img_archives ON imgs.imgs_id = img_archives.old_img_id 
    AND img_archives.id =  3
    SET img_name = "test"
```

Comment: Im trying your solution and I keep getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM imgs INNER JOIN